# Installing postgres gem when database is on a different server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems, centos, pg

My database is on a different server to the application. When I run "bundle" I get the following error:

> No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again
>   with  --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config

How do I set the pg config path if pg is not actually installed on the application server? I have also tried:

> bundle config build.pg --without-pg_config

Thanks

Comment: You need to install the client libraries on the app server or you can't install the `pg` gem.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Add this as an answer and I'll approve it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Ruby PostgreSQL interface (AKA the pg gem) is just a thin wrapper around the PostgreSQL client C libraries. You need to install the PostgreSQL client libraries and headers or you can't install the pg gem. You don't need a whole PostgreSQL installation on your app server, just the client development libraries, the package is probably called something like "libpg-dev" or "libpq-dev".

Comment: Thanks. I now have a new problem relating to this so wondered if you could advise. The error I now get is No such file or directory. Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"? Do I have to have had the PG server running on the app server for these files to exist? Thanks

Comment: @sebastyuiop: Sounds like you're trying to connect to a PostgreSQL server on localhost rather than the remote host. Check your connection set up.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm using Rails and I had specified a hostname parameter but it should have been host. All working now :)